# What is the web_modules Folder

Tags: webpack, package-managers

In `webpack`, there is mention of a `web_modules` folder in the documentation. It mentions that by default `webpack` will load modules from several folders if you use the default `require('package')` instead of a "real" path like `require('./package')`. However, the docs do not mention what this folder does. Is it obsolete or not used so much, or is it just something we are supposed to know/figure out while using `webpack`?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything special to `web_modules` apart from the fact that it is [included in load paths](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js#L92) for resolving modules and loaders if [target configuration setting](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target) is one of `web (default)`, `web_worker` or `async-node`.

Comment: So...is this where users put their modules or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to https://www.npmjs.com/package/webmodules. It says that webmodules assists in installing external dependencies when using webpack and browserify.

If you have installed webmodules, then you can use **$ wpm install packagename** to install some package just like npm. The difference is that  the packages is located in web_modules folder when installed.